# I'm Working with a button command, but can't see what's wrong with this code using elseif statements

Tags: excel, vba

What this code is supposed to do is that if you have a number in `cell 2,2` and it's between a range of those if statements, it will give you a number in `cell 3,3`.  The problem is that it only works on the first 3 statements.  The fourth one doesn't work.  It gives you number 1 instead of number 2.

*note: the program uses more statements but this is just to show that the problem is after the third statement, and sorry for my English.

```
Cell 3,6= 5

Cell 3,7= 10

'MEC
If sheet1.Cells(2, 2) = Empty Then
            sheet3.Cells(3, 3) = ""
            sheet4.Cells(3, 3) = 0

'MEC limited
ElseIf sheet2.Cells(2, 2) = 1 Then
    sheet3.Cells(3, 3) = 0

'MEC aceptable
ElseIf sheet1.Cells(2, 2) > 1 < sheet.Cells(3, 6) Then
    sheet3.Cells(3, 3) = 1

'MEC Good
ElseIf sheet1.Cells(2, 2) > 5 <= sheet2.Cells(3, 7) Then
    sheet3.Cells(3, 3) = 2                 
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Which sheet are you referring to in this line?  `ElseIf sheet1.Cells(2, 2) > 1 < sheet.Cells(3, 6) Then`  ... On the second half?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a typo in your sheets for 'MEC Aceptable.  **`sheet.Cells`**.  Judging by the context, it looks like it should be `Sheet2.Cells`

```
ElseIf sheet1.Cells(2, 2) > 1 < sheet.Cells(3, 6) Then
```

In addition to that, try using `Select Case`.  You can use IF statements, but `Select Case` gets handy when you have many `ElseIf`s

```
Select Case (Sheet1.Cells(2, 2).Value)

    Case Is = ""
        Sheet3.Cells(3, 3) = ""
        Sheet4.Cells(3, 3) = 0
    Case Is = 1
        Sheet3.Cells(3, 3) = 0
    Case Is <= Sheet2.Cells(3, 6) 'There was typo in your orig code.. Sheet2?
        Sheet3.Cells(3, 3) = 1
    Case Is <= Sheet2.Cells(3, 7)
        Sheet3.Cells(3, 3) = 2

End Select
```

Comment: Good catch! I totally missed that typo.

Comment: sorry, its beacause it was in in spanish (instead of sheet is hoja), the typo was when i translated the code, the original code its fine.

Comment: As if figuring out the code isn't tricky enough without having to translate to English just to ask the question.  Bless you for that.  Still, which `hoja` is it?  `Hoja1` or `Hoja2`?

Comment: its Hoja2 and Thank you, for the answer

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you have a couple of languages confused here. The VBA method of writing the third and fourth comparisons is closer to,

```
If Sheet1.Cells(2, 2) = Empty Then
            Sheet3.Cells(3, 3) = ""
            Sheet4.Cells(3, 3) = 0
'MEC limited
ElseIf Sheet2.Cells(2, 2) = 1 Then
        Sheet3.Cells(3, 3) = 0
'MEC aceptable
ElseIf Sheet1.Cells(2, 2) > 1 And Sheet1.Cells(2, 2) < Sheet2.Cells(3, 6) Then
        Sheet3.Cells(3, 3) = 1
'MEC Good
ElseIf Sheet1.Cells(2, 2) > 5 And Sheet1.Cells(2, 2) <= Sheet2.Cells(3, 7) Then
        Sheet3.Cells(3, 3) = 2
End If
```

There is still some priority in these statements. If B2 is 6 then it is greater than 1 and greater than 5. Depending on what is in F3 and G3, the fourth condition may never be reached. Given your example of F3 being 5 it should be OK.